# while print pdf report it takes too much loading time

Tags: pdf, odoo, qweb

I am using odoo 11 CE. while i am printing report from odoo(any pdf report) it take too much time.

I have also tried with different wkhtmltopdf version.

I have also tried to with setting the system parameter report.url but still didn't get success.

I have track the odoo code and found the piece of code for from where it is stop.

on odoo source odoo11/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_actions_report.py.

in above file inside the method _run_wkhtmltopdf(), please find the line  out, err = process.communicate()

while execution of this above line, it stop the execution and odoo show loading....

I am using CentOS.

please help me to solve this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: How long is "too much time"?

Comment: around 5 minutes take to print. and showing loading....